# How to get count incremental by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a count of rows with incremental dates.

My table looks like this:

```
ID name status create_date
1  John AC     2016-01-01 00:00:26.513
2  Jane AC     2016-01-02 00:00:26.513
3  Kane AC     2016-01-02 00:00:26.513
4  Carl AC     2016-01-03 00:00:26.513
5  Dave AC     2016-01-04 00:00:26.513
6  Gina AC     2016-01-04 00:00:26.513
```

Now what I want to return from the SQL is something like this:

```
Date        Count
2016-01-01  1
2016-01-02  3
2016-01-03  4
2016-01-04  6
```

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @swe The way I ask wasn't clear enough?

Comment: your question, translatet to an abstract question, is: can you please do my work. if you read the howtoask carefully, you will find, that you should for example explain, what you tried, and why it failed etc. You will find help better than. but its up to you. this is a poor question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `COUNT() OVER ()` without `PARTITION BY`,by using `ORDER BY`. It will give you the cumulative sum.Use `DISTINCT` to filter out the duplicate values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(create_date AS DATE) [Date],
       COUNT(create_date) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(create_date AS DATE)) as [COUNT]
FROM [YourTable]
```

Comment: It's almost what I want, but I am getting duplicated dates result. 
2010-02-25 1
2010-03-29 3
2010-03-29 3
2010-04-04 7
2010-04-04 7

Comment: still not correct though as some of the dates are missing

Comment: @JibinBalachandran why `distinct` and `count ()over()`? requested logic looks like a trivial `group by` with the same cast to date as you implemented.

Comment: @IvanStarostin If you use `group by`, I guess you will get count as `2` for `2016-01-02`. It will partition according to `DATE`.But that's not what OP wants.What you say?

Comment: @Jibin is right, the count should be carried forward and counted as the date increases.

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.date,count(r.date) count
from
(
    select id,name,substring(convert(nvarchar(50),create_date),1,10) date
    from tblName
) r
group by r.date
```

In this code, in the subquery part,
I select the first 10 letter of date which is converted from dateTime to nvarchar so I make like '2016-01-01'. (which is not also necessary but for make code more readable I prefer to do it in this way).
Then with a simple group by I have date and date's count.

Comment: With explanation your answer will even become better and more useful for others trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT create_date, COUNT(create_date) as [COUNT]
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(create_date AS DATE) create_date
    FROM [YourTable]
) T
GROUP BY create_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, you need a continuous dates list, Does it make sense?
This sample only generating one-month data.

```
    CREATE TABLE #tt(ID INT, name VARCHAR(10), status VARCHAR(10), create_date DATETIME)
    INSERT INTO #tt

    SELECT 1,'John','AC','2016-01-01 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 2,'Jane','AC','2016-01-02 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 3,'Kane','AC','2016-01-02 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 4,'Carl','AC','2016-01-03 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 5,'Dave','AC','2016-01-04 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 6,'Gina','AC','2016-01-04 00:00:26.513' UNION
    SELECT 7,'Tina','AC','2016-01-08 00:00:26.513'
    SELECT * FROM #tt

    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d,sv.number,n.FirstDate)) AS [Date],COUNT(n.num) AS [Count]
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(t.create_date)OVER() AS FirstDate,DATEDIFF(d,MIN(t.create_date)OVER(),t.create_date) AS num FROM  #tt AS t
    ) AS n ON n.num<=sv.number
    WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number>=0 AND MONTH(DATEADD(d,sv.number,n.FirstDate))=MONTH(n.FirstDate)
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d,sv.number,n.FirstDate))
```

```
Date       Count
---------- -----------
2016-01-01 1
2016-01-02 3
2016-01-03 4
2016-01-04 6
2016-01-05 6
2016-01-06 6
2016-01-07 6
2016-01-08 7
2016-01-09 7
2016-01-10 7
2016-01-11 7
2016-01-12 7
2016-01-13 7
2016-01-14 7
2016-01-15 7
2016-01-16 7
2016-01-17 7
2016-01-18 7
2016-01-19 7
2016-01-20 7
2016-01-21 7
2016-01-22 7
2016-01-23 7
2016-01-24 7
2016-01-25 7
2016-01-26 7
2016-01-27 7
2016-01-28 7
2016-01-29 7
2016-01-30 7
2016-01-31 7
2017-01-01 7
2017-01-02 7
2017-01-03 7
2017-01-04 7
2017-01-05 7
2017-01-06 7
2017-01-07 7
2017-01-08 7
2017-01-09 7
2017-01-10 7
2017-01-11 7
2017-01-12 7
2017-01-13 7
2017-01-14 7
2017-01-15 7
2017-01-16 7
2017-01-17 7
2017-01-18 7
2017-01-19 7
2017-01-20 7
2017-01-21 7
2017-01-22 7
2017-01-23 7
2017-01-24 7
2017-01-25 7
2017-01-26 7
2017-01-27 7
2017-01-28 7
2017-01-29 7
2017-01-30 7
2017-01-31 7
2018-01-01 7
2018-01-02 7
2018-01-03 7
2018-01-04 7
2018-01-05 7
2018-01-06 7
2018-01-07 7
2018-01-08 7
2018-01-09 7
2018-01-10 7
2018-01-11 7
2018-01-12 7
2018-01-13 7
2018-01-14 7
2018-01-15 7
2018-01-16 7
2018-01-17 7
2018-01-18 7
2018-01-19 7
2018-01-20 7
2018-01-21 7
2018-01-22 7
2018-01-23 7
2018-01-24 7
2018-01-25 7
2018-01-26 7
2018-01-27 7
2018-01-28 7
2018-01-29 7
2018-01-30 7
2018-01-31 7
2019-01-01 7
2019-01-02 7
2019-01-03 7
2019-01-04 7
2019-01-05 7
2019-01-06 7
2019-01-07 7
2019-01-08 7
2019-01-09 7
2019-01-10 7
2019-01-11 7
2019-01-12 7
2019-01-13 7
2019-01-14 7
2019-01-15 7
2019-01-16 7
2019-01-17 7
2019-01-18 7
2019-01-19 7
2019-01-20 7
2019-01-21 7
2019-01-22 7
2019-01-23 7
2019-01-24 7
2019-01-25 7
2019-01-26 7
2019-01-27 7
2019-01-28 7
2019-01-29 7
2019-01-30 7
2019-01-31 7
2020-01-01 7
2020-01-02 7
2020-01-03 7
2020-01-04 7
2020-01-05 7
2020-01-06 7
2020-01-07 7
2020-01-08 7
2020-01-09 7
2020-01-10 7
2020-01-11 7
2020-01-12 7
2020-01-13 7
2020-01-14 7
2020-01-15 7
2020-01-16 7
2020-01-17 7
2020-01-18 7
2020-01-19 7
2020-01-20 7
2020-01-21 7
2020-01-22 7
2020-01-23 7
2020-01-24 7
2020-01-25 7
2020-01-26 7
2020-01-27 7
2020-01-28 7
2020-01-29 7
2020-01-30 7
2020-01-31 7
2021-01-01 7
2021-01-02 7
2021-01-03 7
2021-01-04 7
2021-01-05 7
2021-01-06 7
2021-01-07 7
2021-01-08 7
2021-01-09 7
2021-01-10 7
2021-01-11 7
2021-01-12 7
2021-01-13 7
2021-01-14 7
2021-01-15 7
2021-01-16 7
2021-01-17 7
2021-01-18 7
2021-01-19 7
2021-01-20 7
2021-01-21 7
2021-01-22 7
2021-01-23 7
2021-01-24 7
2021-01-25 7
2021-01-26 7
2021-01-27 7
2021-01-28 7
2021-01-29 7
2021-01-30 7
2021-01-31 7
```

Comment: That result would be what I want, but the query seems complicated.